# How to append multiple data to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**I have a file called updatelog where I would like to be adding new updates to it**

I tried:

```
date; message >> updatelog.txt
date + message >> updatelog.txt
date & message >> updatelog.txt
date | message >> updatelog.txt
date && message >> updatelog.txt
```

But *nothing* seems to work, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is `message`?

Comment: message would be the update; ex: Fri Oct 29 04:06:29 CEST 2021 Minor bugs fixed

Comment: Like a string? you want to add the date and a string to your file?

Comment: Yes, I think that could be, but it doesn't work like in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
date >> updatelog.txt && echo "A sample message" >> updatelog.txt
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, that was it. I was trying to do it all in once